# Помогите преобразовать ответ из списка в строку

Tags: python, список

*Пользователь по команде “ads” может добавить новую полку*

```py
def ads():
    shelf = input("Введите номер полки: ")
    for direct in directories.items():
        if shelf in direct[0]:
            print(f"Такая полка уже существует. Текущий перечень полок: 
{list(directories.keys())}")
            break
    else:
        directories[shelf] = []
        print(f"Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок: {list(directories.keys())}")
 
ads()
```

```
Введите номер полки: 5
Такая полка уже существует. Текущий перечень полок: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Нужно убрать квадратные скобки... понимаю, что нужен метод `join`... отдельно получается записать вывод полок строкой : `print(",".join(directories.keys()))`; а в программе чет никак...что куда джойнить надо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейшее, как вы и задумывали

```py
print(f"Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок: {', '.join(list(directories.keys()))}")
```

в f-строке вы спокойно можете применять такого типа обработки, в этом нет ничего зазорного.

Comment: Благодарю!!!!! теперь всё встало на свои места в голове

Comment: @ИванХудяков на здоровье. Обратите внимание на эту тему [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**вариант 1:**

```
print(f"Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок: {', '.join(directories.keys())}")
```

**вариант 2:**

```
print(f"Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок:", ', '.join(directories.keys()))
```

**вариант 3:**

```
print("Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок: ", end="")
print(*directories.keys(), sep=", ")
```

**вариант 4 (для словаря):**

```
print(f"Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок:", ', '.join(directories))
```

Comment: Спасибо, друг!!! Весь мозг уже сломал, уже два часа ходил рядом да около и получал 'str' object is not callable